# Rails: Undefined method 'name' in 'user' factory OR Undefined Method for all factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I am currently using RSpec and Factory_Bot_Rails gems for testing an application, but I am running into the issue below.

When using factory_bot_rails version 5.0.2 gem, my factories now all give me an Undefined Method error for all my registered factories. If I downgrade the version of the gem to 4.11 it works.

For example for my users factory, which has **name** as one of the defined attributes, it displays the error

**Undefined method 'name' in 'user' factory**

I have tried so hard to fix this issue but it's not been feasible.

Any form of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here's how I solved the issue**

From the blog by Thoughtbot, I came to realize that statically defined attributes have been deprecated and then removed from  factory_bot >= 5.0. And so rather than use statically defined attributes for your factories, use dynamically defined attributes. That is, insert curly brackets **{}** around every defined attribute in your factory

Here's an example

**Use Dynamically defined attributes**

```
factory :robot do
  name { "Ralph" }
  email { "ralph@example.com" }
end
```

**And not statically defined attributes**

```
factory :robot do
  name "Ralph"
  email  "ralph@example.com"
end
```

You can read up more about it here

[Deprecating static attributes in factory_bot 4.11](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/deprecating-static-attributes-in-factory_bot-4-11)